# Ruby: convert list of jpegs to flv file

Tags: ruby, jpeg, flv

I need to write a Ruby script that can take a collection of jpeg files and creat a slideshow of them in .flv format. the .flv file then needs to be stored into a database.

Does anyone know what libraries/gems/I'm going to need to get this started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**FFmpeg**](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) is capable of *converting single images to a .flv movie*. [This is](http://www.ffmpeg.org/faq.html#SEC14) how it's done.

FFmpeg is a command line tool which is very powerful and widely accepted. (Even video professionals like putpat.tv use that.) The documentation can be found [here](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html).

There is also a [ffmpeg gem for Ruby](http://github.com/polly/ffmpeg). This is a DSL that should make your life easier.

**But:**

It is no slideshow library. You don't have a slideshow user interface, you can just create a movie out of it.

For *slideshows*, the best available solution (imho) is [**Scribd.com**](http://www.scribd.com/). It can convert slideshows from various formats and provides a nice user interface. You probably would have to join the jpegs in another format first. (PDF?) Then, there is also a plugin available for Ruby ([scribd-fu](http://www.railslodge.com/plugins/1042-scribd-fu)). However, it is not intended to be stored in a database.

Thus, I cannot provide the perfect solution to you. And I would be curious about better recommendations...

Comment: yeah, i was looking at an open source for ffmpeg but had no idea they had a ruby gem for it! thanks a lot. I'll let you know how that solution goes.